# get uploaded image dimensions with javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, upload, dimensions

also try this but for me it isnt working.

[Determining image file size + dimensions via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript)

i upload image, insert it on page through jquery and want to create div around inserted image, but dont know image dimensions.

```
$("#temp_image").html('<img src="uploads/obr1.jpg" alt="" id="tmp" />');
var img = document.getElementById('temp_image');
alert(img.clientWidth);
```

it show me 0, what is wrong ?

also tried:

```
var oImg = new Image();
oImg.src = 'uploads/obr1.jpg;
if (oImg.complete) {
  alert(oImg.width)
}
```

it shows me 0 too.

where is problem ? thanks

Comment: Follow this link you will get help
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13572209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
$("#temp_image").html('<img src="uploads/obr1.jpg" alt="" id="tmp" />');
var img = document.getElementById('tmp');
alert(img.clientWidth);
```

You are currently trying to get the width of the containing div (#temp_image), not the image.

Also, if you are using jQuery, you can just do:

```
$("#temp_image").html('<img src="uploads/obr1.jpg" alt="" id="tmp" />');
alert($('#tmp').width());
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = document.getElementById('temp_image');
```

doesn't actually get you the image element, it gets the element containing the image. You should try

```
var img = document.getElementById('tmp');
```

or

```
var img = $('#tmp')[0];
```

instead. Also make sure that the image is actually visible when you're getting it's dimensions, as `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` will be zero if the element is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your method and it's working. You just didn't wrote it well. You forgot to close quotes.

```
var oImg = new Image();
oImg.src = 'uploads/obr1.jpg';
if (oImg.complete) {
  alert(oImg.width)
}
```