# javascript validation check specific height and wigth input type file

Tags: javascript, file, validation

i found this code on online its checking only file types, How to add file height and file wight and also file size to this jquery function
i found this code on online its checking only file types, How to add file height and file wight and also file size to this jquery function

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.checkFileType = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            allowedExtensions: [],
            success: function() {},
            error: function() {}
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            $(this).on('change', function() {
                var value = $(this).val(),
                    file = value.toLowerCase(),
                    extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

                if ($.inArray(extension, options.allowedExtensions) == -1) {
                    options.error();
                    $(this).focus();
                } else {
                    options.success();

                }

            });

        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Calling

```
$(function() {
    $('#shop_logo').checkFileType({
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg'],
        success: function() {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Only jpg images');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look [here for filesize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading), and [here for dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572129/is-it-possible-to-check-dimensions-of-image-before-uploading)

Comment: javascript only has access to the html on your page. Not to files. Maybe the html contains code like <img height="200" width="300" src="imgfilename.jpg">. Do you wish to extract data from there? Or how do you have access to the files in question?

Comment: When uploading files, the basic functionality works through filenames. Checking extension is part of checking filename, that is easy. Checking image dimension is much more complex. Are you prepared for that complexity?

Comment: For files size, do you need to support Internet Explorer 8 or 9 or Opera mini? See support overview at http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi