# HTML5 Form Check image width and height and alert if bigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

EDIT

NOT A DUPLICATED

Need to stop the form submit if the file is bigger in dimension not in size. Some answers in other posts are about file size, my question is about dimensions. Size and dimensions are 2 different things ...

I am using the following form to upload images. It is working fine but because it is a store and I want the catalog of products to looks nice I need the images uploaded to be exactly 200px width and 200px height. If the image is bigger in width or height I need to show an alert so the uploader chose another image or edit the one he is trying to upload.

```
<form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    Upload image:
    <input id="image-file" type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#image-file').bind('change', function() {
            alert('here we have to do something');
        });
    </script>

</form>
```

Comment: google search found me a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation

Comment: file size is not the same as width and height

Comment: my previous link-edit was about "size", using the File API. This one is directly related to width + height validation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript

Comment: you know the answer you marked as correct is a copy and paste of another question/answer :) this is a duplicate.

Comment: Then show me the link to the exact other solution and I will believe you... I readed a lot of other similar answers and no one is about not submit a form if image is bigger in only width and height. Also the guy answering fixed the code for what I need. I do not need to check if the file is 10 MB or 2 MB I need to stop the form submit if the image is larger in dimension. Dimension is not the same as size ... Show me the link and solution

Comment: The link `Is it possible to check dimensions of image before uploading?` in jusysayno's answer is where he got the content of his answer from -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572129/is-it-possible-to-check-dimensions-of-image-before-uploading#answer-13572240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate? Taken from answer here and adapted for you:

[Is it possible to check dimensions of image before uploading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572129/is-it-possible-to-check-dimensions-of-image-before-uploading)

I would agree with above answer and do it on the form submit:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#ImageForm").submit( function( e ) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault(); //Stop the submit for now
                                //Replace with your selector to find the file input in your form
    var fileInput = $(this).find("#image-file")[0],
        file = fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0];
 console.log(file)
    if( file ) {
        var img = new Image();

        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL( file );

        img.onload = function() {
            var width = img.naturalWidth,
                height = img.naturalHeight;

            window.URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );

            if( width <= 200 && height <= 200) {
                form.submit();
            }
            else {
                alert('too big');
            }
        };
    }
    else { //No file was input or browser doesn't support client side reading
        form.submit();
    }

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ImageForm" method="post">

    Upload image:
    <input id="image-file" type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

As the answer in my link says you need to also check this server side as a) you cannot ever trust the client b) older browsers might not work.

Comment: Seems like you are the only that understand the difference between check file size and checking width-height... I will give it a try

Comment: no working I tested with Chrome and the forms submits without warning

Comment: Fixed it. I'd messad up the $("#ImageForm") selector without having a '#'. Js Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uL1xgjbp/1/

Comment: I have changed this to a <= so that if the image is smaller than 200 or equal to 200 then it will submit. Otherwise it will show alert box.

Comment: It is working almost perfect so I mark your solution as correct.

Comment: The only thing is, that I get 2 alerts now the "hello and the too big" but it seems like you edited it

Comment: I tested now and it works perfect, up to 200 x200 no warning and file submits, from 201 x 201 px it gets the warning and the image does not submits. Thanks a lot very much

Comment: All good! Yes I added some unnecessary alerts when testing it out. Glad to help!

Comment: I am trying to make the javascript alert of your code looks nice, any ideas?  here is the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428583/making-a-jquery-alert-box-with-current-code

Comment: Isn't there an answer in the question linked?