# Making a jquery alert box with current code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to make a jquery alert box but nothing seems to works. Here is the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="dialog" title="Attention!" style="display:none">
    here we show the alert
</div>
```

now here is a long form with many input texts on of them is to upload image exactly 200px width and 200px height if bigger in dimension we show alert. Here is the uggly alert

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#productos").submit(function (e) {
        var form = this; e.preventDefault();
        var fileInput = $(this).find("#file")
        [0], file = fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]; console.log(file)
        if (file) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            img.onload = function () {
                var width = img.naturalWidth, height = img.naturalHeight;
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
                if (width <= 200 && height <= 200) { form.submit(); } else
                { alert('THIS IS AN UGGLY ALERT WE WANT TO CHANGE'); }
            };
        } else { form.submit(); }
    });
});
```

Here is the code to the pretty nice alert using the first lines of code

NOTE: THE FOLLOWING LINES OF CODE HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH MY CODE, IT JUST SHOW A NICE ALERT BUT MUST BE IMPLEMENTED IN SOME WAY WITH MY CODE

```
<script>
    function check_domain_input()
    {        
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog(); // Shows the new alert box.

        var domain_val = document.getElementsByName('domain');

        if (domain_val[0].value.length > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

END

Here is what I tried but is not working, mixing both codes

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#productos").submit(function (e) {
        var form = this; e.preventDefault(); var fileInput = $(this).find("#file")[0],
        file = fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]; console.log(file)
        if (file) {
            var img = new Image(); img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            img.onload = function () {
                var width = img.naturalWidth, height = img.naturalHeight;
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
                if (width <= 200 && height <= 200) {
                    form.submit();
                } else {
                    $("#dialog").dialog();
                } //here I need to do something but I do not know what

            };
        } else { form.submit(); }
    });
});
```

Here is the working demo alert I got from the net but I need to mix both codes to make it work

http://jsfiddle.net/8cypx/12/

Comment: Not able to find any DOM with name `domain`

Comment: Edited the question, this domain name code is an example of the pretty alert box and this code must be mixed in some way with my uggly alert code

Comment: Are you including jquery as well as jquery-ui? Do you get any console errors? What happens/doesnt happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these

1.You have all elements with same id  in the HTML as you name them in script #productos ,file

2.Make sure #file is inside the form with id productos

3.As per

> upload image exactly 200px width and 200px height if bigger in dimension we show alert.

but you have this condition

```
     if (width <= 200 && height <= 200)
```

which is wrong since it allows any image with size below 200x200px and not just 200x200px , the correct condition is

```
     if (width == 200 && height == 200)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cypx/269/

Comment: Your answer is correct but I see the problem now. I am using Jquery 2 and it seems like the dialog DIV is only compatible with Jquery 1. Is it ?

Comment: Well version dependencies do exits but only for jquery so given any old jqueryui you can always use the latest jquery without any problem but its not true the other direction ie you can't use latest jqueryui with older jquery so i think using Jquery 2 here may not be an issue .You can see [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/) what version are supported .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some errors in the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#productos").submit(function (e) {
        var form = this; e.preventDefault(); 
        var fileInput = $(this).find("#file")[0],
        file = fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]; console.log(file)
        if (file) {
            var img = new Image(); 
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            img.onload = function () {
                var width = img.naturalWidth, height = img.naturalHeight;
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
                if (width <= 200 && height <= 200) {
                    form.submit();
                } else {
                    $("#dialog").dialog();
                } //here I need to do something but I do not know what

            };
        } else { 
        //form.submit(); 
        console.log('form.submit');
        }
    });
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/8cypx/270/