# How do I only accept uploaded images with a 1:1 (square) aspect ratio and throw an error otherwise?

Tags: django

The admin is able to upload an image but I would like to restrict it to only being a square image.

Here is my models.py file:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
        null=True, 
        blank=True,)
    author_bio = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name
```

Answer (score 0):

`ImageField` has `height_field` and `width_field` properties, but according to the docs, those only get auto-populated *after* the image is saved.

In order to do it before the image is uploaded, I think you're going to need jQuery. [Check out this question/answer, as it seems like what you want to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572129/is-it-possible-to-check-dimensions-of-image-before-uploading). You would alter that code to compare that `width == height` to check for perfect squareness. AJAX would give you the option of the user uploading the image without the page needing to reload.