# Limit width and height of image on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to limit the width and height of the pic on input field by using html, css and javascript/jquery? I'm trying to limit it for profile photo upload (need the photo to be a perfect square, e.g. 200x200, 300x300)

Comment: You can refer to this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572129/is-it-possible-to-check-dimensions-of-image-before-uploading)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function called getimagesize().

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img.jpg");
```

as can be seen in the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

So, just check the height and width before submitting to the database

Comment: I'm using django though?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the height of width of the image by creating an image from the uploaded file.

```
$("#fileUploadForm").submit(function(e){
var window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var fileInput = $(this).find("input[type=file]")[0],
    file = fileInput.files ? fileInput.files[0] : null;

if( file ) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL( file );

    img.onload = function() {
        var width = img.naturalWidth,
            height = img.naturalHeight;

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL( img.src );

        if( width == height) {//perfect square
            this.submit();
        }
        else {
            //fail
        }
    };
}
});
```