# I want get size and type image before upload?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to get size and type of image before upload by FileUpload, and if size (width and height) = 42px and type was png show the image in img tag

I'm using jQuery and this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showpreview(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
      if (input.files[0].type.match('png')) {
           var q = new Image;
           q.src = e.target.result;
           alert(q.width);
           if (q.height == 42 && q.width == 42) {
              $('#imgprvw').css('visibility', 'visible');
              $('#imgprvw').attr('src', e.target.result);
           } else {
              alert("اندازه تصویر باید 42 در 42 پیکسل باشد");
           }
       } else {
              alert("نوع تصویر باید PNG باشد");
       }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

but when I get q.width or q.height is 0

Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572129/is-it-possible-to-check-dimensions-of-image-before-uploading

Comment: Duplicate `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check image width and height before upload with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript)