# Displaying images uploaded by users in a card with fixed dimensions

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, angular-material, material-design

I want to allow the users of my site to upload images. Each person can submit one image. Then, this image will be displayed inside of a mat-card. I want it to look good on mobile, as well. I have very little experience with this, I don't know how to approach this problem.

Do I force some ratio of the image before I accept the upload? What if someone submits image like 1000x25? If the image is smaller than the card, is it best practice to stretch it to match the card's dimensions? Do I set the fixed width or height? Any pointers on how to approach this would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide us with your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572129/is-it-possible-to-check-dimensions-of-image-before-uploading