# Is there any way to know the size (in bytes) of received objects in HTML webpages?

Tags: javascript, html

Assuming I have an img tag with src to some image. The browser sends HTTP GET request and in the response I get some image file. Can I get the size of this image file in bytes?
What about other objects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552369/how-to-get-image-size-in-bytes-using-javascript - how about this?

Comment: And also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript