# Get Size in bytes of an Image which is from URL and displayed in an <img> tag

Tags: javascript, image, file, size, getimagesize

I have an  tag that displays the image from an `ng-model`. The `ng-model` vale is a `URL`. I need to get the size in bytes of that particular image for function use. I tried using `$scope.imgModel.files[0].size` but it always returns an error that cannot read property `0` of undefined.

My `ng-model` turned out to be like this

```
$scope.imgModel = "url of image"
```

in my html i have an  tag like this:

```
 <img src="{{imgModel}}" style="width: 100%;" id="imageFile">
```

How can I get the size of imgModel?

Comment: What do you mean by size? Size in bytes or dimensions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen size in bytes

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45409613/3558960).

Comment: that does not answer my question tho