# Predict time to fully load page in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

In javascript, is there anyway to query how large css/js files are, and how large image files are? I have a unique situation where I give a user a preview of a page, and that page can either be the full page, or google's cached text-only version of the page. The text only version loads instantly.

Don't think there is, but figured I would ask.

Maybe Google's index also holds information on page load times, would anyone know how to query this load time?

I want to make my app consider loading the text version of a page if it recognizes that it will take a long time to load the full page.

What I might do is search through the html string for a page, and just count the number of http requests that will be made (each css link, script tag, and img tag) via string manipulation. If there are more than X requests that would be made by inserting and loading that page's full html for the preview, then I'll opt for the instant text version of the page.

Comment: So, Google of course has track of page load times, as discussed here: http://mrcoles.com/blog/google-site-speed-since-when/, anyone have a clue of how to query this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using AJAX like author of an answer done in [THIS TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript).

Making HEAD HTTP AJAX  request can give you header information about given file without downloading its content.

Here is the example from the link:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('HEAD', 'img/test.jpg', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if ( xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
    if ( xhr.status == 200 ) {
      alert('Size in bytes: ' + xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));
    } else {
      alert('ERROR');
    }
  }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

For more info please visit the source where author did a great job showing that solution.