# How to have jQuery get image size in bytes, not image dimensions?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7.1.

After an image loads in the browser window, I want to retrieve its total byte size.  Is there an object name / value for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript/

Comment: Javascript is running on the CLIENT's computer, and if the browser supports HTML5's File API you could actually get the size of an image on the users computer, if of course the user wanted you to. To find the size of images on your server, you will need a SERVER language like PHP or Rails, OR you could do a HEAD request with AJAX to get the filesize or you could load the image in a canvas and get the filesize there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way you can get the image size using jQuery or pure JavaScript. The only way is to get it from server side using ajax.

You can get the image url send it to a service or server side page and have the page or service return the image size.

Answer (score 2):

**here is the jQuery Code to get image size and type with validations ** you can use this code inside the function in your jQuery file

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
{
   var pic_size = $('#profile_pic')[0].files[0].size;//get file size 
   var pic_type = $('#profile_pic')[0].files[0].type;

   var extension = pic_type.split('/').pop().toUpperCase();

    if (extension!="PNG" && extension!="JPG" && extension!="GIF" && extension!="JPEG" || pic_size>=2048000)
    {
        alert ("Please Select PNG,JPG,GIF,JPEG Image Only and File Size not Greater than 2MB");
        $( "#profile_pic" ).focus()
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this there is javascript code

```
$("#file_id")[0].files[0].size
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You'll probably need a server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

You can get file size by below

```
$("#selector")[0].files[0].size
```

And Also You can get file format by below

```
$("#selector")[0].files[0].type
```

Also if you want validation like file size is not more than 2 MB than you can try by this

```
var mS_totalBytes = this.files[0].size;
var mS_size = Math.floor(mS_totalBytes/1024000); // its on MB
```

use if else condition based on your requirements like below

```
var mS_totalBytes = this.files[0].size;
var _size = Math.floor(mS_totalBytes/1024000);   // in MB
//alert(mS_size);
if(mS_size >= 1){
    jQuery(".ExportAndroidAsset").prop('disabled', true);
    alert("MAximum File Size is 1MB");
    jQuery(".pxel_Bar").css("width","1%");
    jQuery(".pxel_Progress").hide();
    jQuery(".tab-pane .output label").show();
    jQuery('input[name=imagefile]').val('');
}
else{
    jQuery(".ExportAndroidAsset").prop('disabled', false);
    jQuery(".pxel_Progress").show();
    jQuery(".tab-pane .output label").hide();
}
```