# dojo: download image and detect pixel size

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to perform the following task:

1. download an image by a given URL
2. detect the size of that image in pixels or in kb, whatever is easier

Does anybody know a good approach with dojo or with "plain JavaScript"?

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this simple approach sufficient?  I'm not sure if you meant "download" to mean "save to the client's computer" or simply "retrieve from the remote server".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        alert("Width: " + image.width + ", Height: " + image.height);
    }
    image.src = "http://placehold.it/350x150";
</script>
```