# HTML or Javascript Questions - Image Test

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of hundreds of festivals and I'm trying to determine how to effectively use an if statement to test when:

this type of page  - http://www1.sk-static.com/images/media/profile_images/events/18704054/col4

is different than this

this type of page - http://www2.sk-static.com/images/media/profile_images/events/18709809/col4

As you can see in the the top link, there is no image, but actually there is... it is a blank image. I have a back-up image in this case but I can't seem to figure out how to test if the image is blank or not since both links are valid with 'images' on them.

Comment: can we see some code?

Comment: There isn't much code to show here other than: <div class="image"><img class="festival-icon"  src="<%= festival.fest_icon %>"></div>. Where festival.fest_icon is the link(s) above. I suppose I could test the size of the image in Ruby/Rails before saving it to the table. But maybe client side is better, dunno yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the memory size of the image, if you are using any server side scripting language.

as i can see from you above images first image(blank) is of size **`237 Bytes`** where as second image is of size **`87.9 KB`**

as blank image size is less you can check the size and show alternative image.

see this question this may help you

[determining image file size dimensions via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript)

Comment: That could work, but the images are really just saved as string, they don't appear until on the client side. I don't see anyway for JS to compute size only width, height, naturalWidth, naturalHeight

Comment: how do you fetch the images? is it from database?

Answer (score 0):

You can test for the **image name** which is blank image and obviously this image will be where the blank image would be. So if you get background image with such name apply your condition.