# How to find image data size using javascript?

Tags: javascript

On a webpage, once images have been downloaded and rendered, I need to determine an image's file size (kb) within the browser context (so I could display that info on the page, just below the image)

Comment: Maybe new XmlHttpRequest().getResponseHeader('Content-Length') is useful.

Comment: Asked and answered on here already.  Please search before asking.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably with a `HEAD` request returning the `Content-Length`:

```
function fileSize(img, func) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('HEAD', img.src, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      func(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length')) 
    }
  }
  xhr.send()
}
```

### Usage

```
fileSize(imgNode, function(size) {
  // ...
})
```