# How to stretch small images inside a container preserving its aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Let's say I have a 100x100 container which will be populated with different images via javascript.
If the first image is e.g. 25x50, i want to display it inside the container centered at 50x100.
Another image could be 50x25, but must be displayed at 100x50.
Making a CSS with width=100% and height=100% would render all images to 100x100.
How can I do that using CSS?

```
.container
{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}

.image
{
    max-height:100px;
    max-width:100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as a background image and use `background-size: cover;`

The other option is to check which side of the image is longer and set on that side to 100% and the other side to auto.

[Determining image file size + dimensions via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript)