# Phonegap image weight

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm doing a phonegap app and I take a picture with this method:

```
// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {

    // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    //
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 50,
        destinationType : destinationType.DATA_URL,
        targetWidth: 100
    });
}
```

But I want to know if there is a way in phonegap to know the weight of the photo that's taken.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into this and it seems that the [PhoneGap Camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/af18483d6970b32a22f016292d3d2cb921eedb00/doc/index.md) cannot help you with finding out the weight of the produced image.

To explain what happens when you have have taken picture you could do this in your success function:

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}
```

You end up with a JavaScript Image object. You can read more here [Determining image file size + dimensions via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript) about determining image file size in JavaScript, there does not seem to be an easy straightforward solution unfortunately.

Comment: Yes that-s what I do with the picture. But at the same time I send it through ajax to a server and I need to know the weight of the image. I'm trying to get the base64 picture from the server to work with it in php. But I can't decode the photo yet. Once I get the photo from php it will be easier to know the weight.

Comment: So you are asking for size computing in PHP? Have you tried strlen(base64_decode($encoded_data)); ?

Comment: no I wanted to know the size of the photo before sending it to the server.