# Determine image 404 / filesize with JS

Tags: javascript

I have this function in JS that preloads images:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images
var preloaded_images = [];
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        preloaded_images[i] = new Image();
        preloaded_images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
    }
}
```

However, some images I try to preload throw 404 errors. How can I detect a 404 within this function, without trying to add the image to the DOM?

Comment: `preloaded_images[i].onerror = function() { ... } `?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining image file size + dimensions via Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript)

Comment: Why not simply make the images available? Or, if they are not to be made available, remove them from your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach the `onerror` eventHandler:

```
...
preloaded_images[i].onerror = function() {
    // the image couldn't be loaded..
}
...
```

And if you want to know it was loaded successful, you would do:

```
...
preloaded_images[i].onload = function() {
    // the image was loaded successful..
}
...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhnkg6ax/)