# Get image size from existing image by location angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to validate existing images size which have been saved before. Value stored in database is just image name.

Here is my html code

```
<div ng-repeat="image in stored.images">
     <img ng-src="image_folder/{{image.name}}" />
</div>
```

Is there any way to get image size (in KB/MB not height and width) from image path in angularjs? or should do something in java controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining image file size + dimensions via Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript)

Comment: @mevius ain't work for angular, only javascript

Comment: That's wrong. Angular *is* JavaScript (as is the answer you selected as correct)

Comment: @mevius i mean there's no default angular function, but yes with javascript

Comment: @mevius He was hoping to find an angular solution, and he chose the javascript solution after realising that there is no way to accomplish this with Angular JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this will not be possible with Angular as the only was with javascript to do this is to execute an AJAX request for the image then read the

```
getResponseHeader('Content-Length')
```

Header property. Angular JS is not intended for these kinds of operations.

```js
function httpGetFileSize(theUrl){
 //FETCH Data From Server
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("HEAD", theUrl , false );
 xmlhttp.send();   
 return xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
}
```

That is the javascript answer to this problem. You could also do this server side with PHP or ASP

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to do a `HEAD` request, rather than a `GET`? Or is there no difference here?

Comment: Yes it would. Sorry thought i changed that when I pasted my normal GET request function in.